# HTML/Jquery mousemove image sequence

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a website with a fullscreen background. The idea is that an image sequence is playing, following the mouse position (left of the page start of the animation, right of the page end of the animation). So when you move your mouse left - right - left the image sequence is playing forward and backward like a timeline.

I tried building this with area mapping in HTML, only I have to create 240 maps but the coordinates are getting messed up (fullscreen / browsers). I know it would be a lot easier to make it in jquery, but I don't know how to get started.

Anyone can help me started? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DEB5C/)*

Just play with the CSS to make it full screen.

HTML:

```
<div id="mmGallery_container">
    <div id="mmGallery">
        // images here
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // roXon mmGallery   
    MouseRelXpos = 0;  
    sumW = 0;
    
    // auto-SET mmGallery_container WIDTH ()
    $('#mmGallery img').each(function(){
        sumW += $(this).width(); // collect all images widths
        $('#mmGallery').width(sumW);//SET gallery WIDTH!
    });        
    // Calculate 'compensation speed': width difference between the gallery container and the gallery
    wDiff1 = $('#mmGallery_container').width();
    wDiff2 = $('#mmGallery').width();
    wDiff = (wDiff2/wDiff1)-1;  //(-1 is for the already existant container width)        
    //#
    
    $("#mmGallery_container").mousemove(function(e) {
        MouseRelXpos = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft); // = mouse pos. 'minus' offsetLeft of this element       
    });
        
    var xSlider = $("#mmGallery");     // cache
    var posX = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        posX += (- MouseRelXpos - posX) / 14; // 14 = speed (higher val = slower animation)
        xSlider.css({marginLeft:  Math.round(posX * wDiff) +'px' }); // instead 'marginLeft' use 'left' for absolute pos. #mmGallery
    }, 10); // 10 = loop timeout
});
```